# Why Math.Ceil give unexpected result when the parameter is calculated variable value?

Tags: delphi, floating-point, ceil

In the following code, the last two calls to `Ceil` give unexpected result. Could you help to comment on the reason?

Furthermore, if the error (or deviation) is random, could I get the expected value?

`Ceil(Calculated_Var_Value) = 7` when `Calculated_Var_Value = 7.0000000000`.

Many thanks!

```
    procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    var
      A, B, C: Extended;
      Val: Extended;
    begin
      ShowMessage(FloatToStr((1.8 - 2.5) / -0.1));
      ShowMessage(FloatToStrF((1.8 - 2.5) / -0.1, ffFixed, 20, 20));
      ShowMessage(FloatToStr(Ceil((1.8 - 2.5) / -0.1)));


      Val := (1.8 - 2.5) / -0.1;
      ShowMessage(FloatToStr(Val));
      ShowMessage(FloatToStrF(Val, ffFixed, 20, 20));
      ShowMessage(FloatToStr(Ceil(Val)));


      Val := (1.8 - 2.5) / -0.1;
      ShowMessage(FloatToStr(Val * 100 / 100));
      ShowMessage(FloatToStrF(Val * 100 / 100, ffFixed, 20, 20));
      ShowMessage(FloatToStr(Ceil(Val * 100 / 100)));


      A := 1.8; B := 2.5; C := -0.1;
      Val := (A - B) / C;
      ShowMessage(FloatToStr(Val));
      ShowMessage(FloatToStrF(Val, ffFixed, 20, 20));
      ShowMessage(FloatToStr(Ceil(Val)));


      A := 1.8; B := 2.5; C := -0.1;
      Val := (A - B) / C;
      ShowMessage(FloatToStr(Val * 100 / 100));
      ShowMessage(FloatToStrF(Val * 100 / 100, ffFixed, 20, 20));
      ShowMessage(FloatToStr(Ceil(Val * 100 / 100)));
    end;
```

Comment: The values aren't what you think they are: http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float

Comment: 0.1 is a recurring number when written in binary, so it's never represented exactly (in the same way that 1/3 is a recurring number when written in decimal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just down to the inherent inaccuracy of floating point arithmetic. Two of your values are not exactly representable in binary floating point, `1.8` and `-0.1`. So, those numbers are approximated by the closest representable values. And that means that it's quite plausible that your equation won't evaluate to exactly `7`.

Now consider your two expressions:

```
Val1 := (1.8 - 2.5) / -0.1;
Val2 := (A - B) / C;
```

The difference between these two is that `Val1` is evaluated at compile time and `Val2` is evaluated at runtime. Now, it's down to the compiler how the constant expression `(1.8 - 2.5) / -0.1` is evaluated. To the best of my knowledge, it's not documented how that will be evaluated.

However, it is clear that the compiler uses a different evaluation method to evaluate the constant expression from that used at runtime. This program illustrates that:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Math;

var
  A, B, C: Extended;
  Val1, Val2: Extended;
begin
  Val1 := (1.8 - 2.5) / -0.1;
  Writeln(Ceil(Val1));

  A := 1.8; B := 2.5; C := -0.1;
  Val2 := (A - B) / C;
  Writeln(Ceil(Val2));

  Writeln(BoolToStr(Val1=7.0, True));
  Writeln(BoolToStr(Val2=7.0, True));
  Writeln(BoolToStr(Val1<Val2, True));

  Readln;
end.
```

Output:

```
7
8
True
False
True
```

So, this shows that `Val1` and `Val2` have different values, and that `Val2` is strictly greater than `7`.

The fundamental problem you have is that of representably of floating point values. Because you are using `Extended`, which uses a binary representation, your decimal input values are not exactly representable. If you want exact arithmetic here, you will need to use a decimal representation.

As always when answering variants of this question, I refer you to the essential reading on the subject: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical rounding error. You can see it when you add this line to your output:

```
ShowMessage(FloatToStr(Val-7));
```